# Hey can anybody tell me what is the meaning of this?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

```
X = df_census.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df_census.iloc[:,-1]
```

what is the meaning of `[:,:-1]` in this and also `[:,-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Following your example: [:,:-1]

The first argument is : which means to get all rows of the dataframe, and :-1 means to return all columns but the last one

In the case of just -1, it means to get the last column